Isometry group of the Fubini-Study metric on complex projective spaces
Let $(\mathbb CP^n,g_{FS})$ be the complex projective space equipped with the standard Fubini-Study metric.
What is the Riemannian isometry group of $(\mathbb CP^n,g_{FS})$? It seems to me that its identity component must be the projective unitary group.

That's correct.  Moreover, the Riemannian isometry group, which has two components, is generated by the projective unitary group together with any  anti-holomorphic isometry.
